# problems when importing tensorflow in Jupiter Notebook

Tags: tensorflow

I am using Jupiter Notebook installed with Anaconda distribution and I want to install Tensorflow.
 I wrote

```
!pip install tensorflow
```

it installed it, but now when I want to import tensorflow, when I type

`import tensorflow as tf`

it gives me an error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795
```

I searched for answers and questions related to this issue but nothing helped me. The most weird is that I managed to install and import tensorflow on another computer like this. I can`t find out what I am missing.